# How to revert local code to previous revision svn

Tags: svn, version-control

I would like to revert only the local code to previous versions.

For extra points, what i would like to do is to revert a folder to a previous version (only locally) and generate a file of differences from the version after it.

e.g. say I have version 100. I want version 99 and a diff between that and 100, then 98 and 99 etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
svn update -r 99
svn diff -r 100
```

Comment: For the lazy like me: `100` stands for "Version you HAVE" and `99` stands for "Version you WANT TO REVERT TO".

Answer (score 6):

```
svn checkout url://repository/path@1234
```

to check out rev no 1234.

```
svn revert -R
```

to revert local modifications.

check [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.history.html) for more

Comment: Do i checkout to my own current working directory or do i need to checkout a new repo?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to revert to a particular revision to debug an older build and this worked like magic:

svn up -r 3340 (or whatever your desired revision number)
I had to resolve all conflicts using "tc" option as I did not care about local changes (checked in everything I cared about prior to reverting)

To get back to head revision was simple too:

svn up

Note: a Better way to revert to a previous SVN revision of a file.